# Syslog local0 local7 and severity levels

Tags: syslog

Why is there 7 different localX facilities in syslog ? My understanding is that we can choose anyone but I am curious and I would like to know why there are 8 facilities.

Any link with "severity" ?

Comment: I do not think this is a duplicate. My question is specificaly to know why there are 8 facilities, not what they are

Comment: There are more than 8 facilities. local0 through local8 are basically extra facilities, on top of all of the other standard ones, that users can use for their own custom uses.